# Why won't the updated variable values display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting initial values on a these variables. I change the values, and they do log correctly, however in the return function, they only display the original values. How do I make sure they show the correct updated values?

I declare my variables:

```
let teamBillableData = [];
let teamMemberBillableAmount = 0;
let teamMemberIndex = 0;
```

Then I change the values:

```
teamBillableData = parsedData.results;
teamMemberIndex = teamBillableData.findIndex(function (teamMember) {
   return teamMember.user_name === teamMemberName;
    })
teamMemberBillableAmount = teamBillableData[teamMemberIndex].billable_amount;
```

When I log the variables, they are correct:

```
console.log(teamMemberIndex); <---- Returns correct new value of 1
console.log(teamMemberBillableAmount); <---- Returns correct new value of 1,221.25
```

However, when I render the values in my return function in my React app, they render the initial values stull:

```
return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h5>{teamMemberIndex}</h5> <---- Returns old original value of 0
          <h5>${teamMemberBillableAmount.toLocaleString()} </h5> <---- Returns old original value of 0
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I assume it's rendering before the values are changed.  But I do not know how to make it render AFTER they values are changed.

Comment: Use `useState` if using functional component else use `this.setState()` for class components.

Answer (score 1):

A React component only re-renders after either its state or its props change.

If you want your component to re-render when a variable changes, you have to add said variable to the component's state

If you're dealing with functional components, look into `useState` hook.

Answer (score 1):

As told by Michael and Shubham you can write a functional component that triggers a rerender each time the state is updated using the useState hook.

An Example could be:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Example() {  
    const [teamMemberBillableAmount, setTeamMemberBillableAmount] = useState(0);// initial state
  
    const clickHandler = () => setTeamMemberBillableAmount(teamMemberBillableAmount + 1); // add 1 to the teamMemberBillableAmount state each time the button is clicked (a rerender will happen)

    return (
        <div>
            <p>The team billable amount is:<strong style={{ color: "red" }}> teamMemberBillableAmount}</strong></p>
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Press me to add +1</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can run and play with this code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yjv65q?file=src/components/Example.js)